# How can I reference the list of objects/materials in a scene using python?

Tags: python, materials, add-on

I am trying to create an add-on that has a feature that allows the user to select up to 5 objects that exist in their scene. To do this I've created 5 enumerators, however, I'm struggling when it comes to the "items" parameter. So far I've figured out that an object is stored in bpy.data.objects[""].name, but I can't find the location of the list/dictionary for all existing objects in the scene in order to reference it in the code.

Is this possible to do? If so how can I code the enumerators to use the list/dictionary of existing objects?

Side Note: I plan on doing this with the list of existing materials within the scene as well, so would it be the same deal as the objects?

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me figure this out, thanks!

[image]

My code:

```
import bpy


class Object_Enums(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    enum1 : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "#1", 
        description= "sample text", 
        items= [
        
        ]
            
    )
    
    enum2 : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "#2", 
        description= "sample text", 
        items= [
        
        ]
            
    )
    
    enum3 : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "#3", 
        description= "sample text", 
        items= [
        
        ]
            
    )
    
    enum4 : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "#4", 
        description= "sample text", 
        items= [
        
        ]
            
    )
    
    enum5 : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "#5", 
        description= "sample text", 
        items= [
        
        ]
            
    )

class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "ADDONNAME"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "ADDONNAME"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        layout.prop(mytool, "enum1")
        layout.prop(mytool, "enum2")
        layout.prop(mytool, "enum3")
        layout.prop(mytool, "enum4")
        layout.prop(mytool, "enum5")

        row = layout.row()


class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Operator"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"
    
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}
    

classes = [Object_Enums, ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]
 
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
        bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= Object_Enums)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Suggest considering a PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object) instead of an EnumProperty. It will give you a drop down of objects for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all of the objects in the scene with

```
for object in context.scene.objects:
    print(object.name)
```

since `context.scene.objects` contains all of the objects in the scene.

If you only want to list each material once

```
material_set = set()
for object in context.scene.objects:
    for material in object.material_slots:
        material_set.add(material)
        
for material in material_set:
    print(material.name)
```

works because each object has a list of material_slots

or you can combine it all

```
for object in context.scene.objects:
    print(object.name)
    for material in object.material_slots:
        print('\t' + material.name)
```

If you want to see which materials each object contains.

Given that you know how to list the objects, it's easy to adapt the loops to use them for your enumerations.

Comment: Oh, duh! Once I read over the code you provided it became glaringly obvious haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that sets have a random access rule so you might experience flickering when iterating over those in the interface.